# Is it okay to use "Moesif Origins and CORS Changer" extension to resolve the CORS error while using API in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, api

I am using an API in my react code and it was issuing CORS error on `npm start`. The Moesif extension resolved the issue but I don't know that is it a good way to resolve this issue as I want this site to be functional by other users as well. And I think that without using this extension it will give an error on other devices.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can't use that api in production  because api provider does not allow you to do that.